# How to get the correct bundle instance if multiple bundles with same ID exist?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am writing a plugin for a host application (Aperture). The plugin is deployed as a bundle and within this bundle there are frameworks needed by this plugin e.g. Sparkle.

The problem is that it is now possible that another plugin is loaded within Aperture, which also has the Sparkle framework embedded. In the Sparkle code the following preprocessor directive is defined, which is used to retrieve Sparkle's `NSBundle` instance:

```
#define SPARKLE_BUNDLE [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"org.andymatuschak.Sparkle"]
```

However if two plugins have their instance of Sparkle each, two bundles with the same identifier exist and of course in my case the wrong one is loaded. Anyhow I would not like to rely on chance here.

#### My Question

Is there a way to load the correct Sparkle bundle, the one which is embedded in my plugin?

I thought about this alternative:

```
#define SPARKLE_BUNDLE [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]
```

I am not sure but I think this would break if the class is subclassed by a file located outside the bundle (like it's done in AppKit, too). Am I correct here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you embedded it, **load it via its path** not via its identifier

```
myPluginBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:self.class];
bundlePath = [myPluginBundle pathForResource:@"Sparkle"type:@"bundle"];
bundle = [NSBundle bundleAtPath:bundlePath];
```

Comment: you can also dynamically load a specific framework. getting rid of the intermediate bundle

Comment: That sounds good. I thought I would have to do more path tinkering. Could be that I have to swizzle the implementation into the right place in the `SUUpdater` class. I was a bit unclear, but the embedded Sparkle framework should be addressed like `[myPluginBundle pathForResource:@"Sparkle"type:@"framework"]`. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: In your first comment are you referring to calling bundleAtPath directly?

Comment: yes. -- check http://pagesofinterest.net/blog/2011/07/detecting-presence-of-a-framework-within-an-nsbundle-plugin/ -- they deal with embedding sparkle in a plugin bundle -- your usecase